# ASP.NET MVC client side validation with jQuery 'loading' image function

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a jQuery function that shows a 'loading' image and disable the submit button when the form is submitted.
I also added Html.EnableClientValidation();

The problem is that when I click the submit button and the form is not valid then I get all the validation error messages but the 'loading' image never stops and the button stays 'disabled'

I want to add functionality that stops the 'loading' image and enables the button when the form is not valid.

I know how to write the jQuery function but I don't know how to integrate it with MVC EnableClientValidation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you are using an AJAX form because you are talking about disabling and enabling the submit button, In this case I would recommend you disabling the submit button just before sending the AJAX request which will ensure that client validation has passed.

If you are using MS AJAX to AJAXify your form the two events you might try are [OnBegin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onbegin.aspx) and [OnComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.oncomplete.aspx):

```
<% Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { 
    OnBegin = "enable" OnComplete = "disable" }) %>
```

If you are using jquery then you could subscribe for the `beforeSend` and `complete` events and this could be achieved globally with [$.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/).

Comment: Thanks, but the script does't get to send data to the server using Ajax because the EnableClientValidation(); stops the form from submitting before the data is sent. Like the function says, its client side validation and not server side validation so I need to use the OnBegin and OnComplete callbacks in the Client side script instead of the Ajax script, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: OnBegin and OnComplete are client side function names.